# Call a webservice when android service is destroyed

Tags: android, web-services, service

there is a function, or is it possible to know if a service, in android, it was destroyed by a user and call a webservice when that happens.
for example: the user sent to background a aplication and destroyed, when we destroy a app, the app calls a webservice.
sorry for my english.

Comment: a service of your application, or a service in general ?

Comment: what i want is call a webservice when the user destroy the app.for example the user send a app to brackground and destroy, before the user kill the app, the app call a webservice to delete token of mobile phone of database

Comment: any app, or your app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a webservice call in your activity's `onPause()`, I wouldn't use `onDestroy()` since its not guaranteed to be called.

API reference is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

Comment: i want when user destroy the app, if i put activity onpause, i 
I don't want call, only the user destroy the app in background

Comment: The user doesn't destroy the app in the background, the framework you write your application on does.  And it doesn't guarantee `onDestroy` will ever be called so if you need to invoke a webservice when things are being torn down you should do it `onPause`, lest you run the risk of losing data.  Think of it in *nix terms of SIGKILL which you can't catch vs. SIGTERM which you can.